# I'm trying to attach an event handler to an HTML table. Works on $(document) but not on $(#tableID)

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I've been working with jQuery to do a lot of event driven programming and I've been told that event handlers should be attached to the closest static parent container. However, when I try to attach the event listener to the table, it doesn't work. I only have it working by watching the entire document. Here's what I have that works:

```
$(document).on("click", "td", function() {
    //do something
})
```

However, I want to get something more like this:

```
$("#tableID").on("click", "td", function() {
    //do something
})
```

The second version doesn't work though. I don't think it ever detects any clicks on my table. Why would this be?

Comment: Is the table dynamically loaded?

Comment: Tried in jsfiddle, it works. http://jsfiddle.net/fLBTP/ Can you provide more info for your case?

Comment: The empty table is made in HTML and then <td>s are added/removed with javascript dynamically. The table is completely loaded by the time I am clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the code after the DOM is ready... or at least after that element is ready.

```
$(function() {
    $("#tableID").on("click", "td", function() {
        //do something
    });
});
```

And of course you need to make sure the ID is correct, and unique.

Comment: Ah that did it. I moved this event listener into my $(document).ready(function{}); and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Because the selector should be a string. Put quotes around it and it should work.

```
$('#tableID').on('click', 'td', function() {
    //do something
});
```

If the table is loaded via AJAX, then the delegate target (which would be the one in `$()`) should be an element present on the page during the execution of this binding code. The usual target is `document` because it's always there. But it's too far up the DOM tree, that's why you are allowed to choose your target.